# jQuery mobile ajax call returning SyntaxError

Tags: jquery, ajax, mobile

I am receiving xhr.status = 200 which means good, but then the following:

```
 SyntaxError: missing ; before statement
```

I cannot find where this error is being thrown. Here is my html:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<div data-role="page" id="login" data-theme="a">
    <div data-role="header" > <!-- data-theme="a" -->
        <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <form name="loginForm" id="loginForm" class="ui-body ui-body-a ui-corner-all" data-ajax="false">
            <fieldset>
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">
                    <input type="text" name="userName" id="userName" value="" placeholder="User ID"/>
                </div>                                 
                <div data-role="fieldcontain">                                     
                    <input type="password" name="userPassword" id="userPassword" value="" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="off"/>
                </div>
                <input type="button" name="submit" id="submit" value="Login" data-theme="d" />
                <p>
                Keep me logged in? <input type="checkbox" name="keepLoggedIn" id="keepLoggedIn" data-role="flipswitch"  data-theme="d"/>
                </p>
            </fieldset>
        </form>                             
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">

    </div>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="second">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h3>Company Logo</h3>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        Upload Photos
    </div>

    <div data-theme="a" data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        <h3>Page footer</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is my javascript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#login', function(){ 

$(document).on('click', '#submit', function() { 

    if($('#userName').val().length > 0 && $('#userPassword').val().length > 0) {
        // Send data to server through the Ajax call
        // action is functionality we want to call and outputJSON is our data
        $.ajax({
            url: "second.cfm",
            data: { action : 'getUser', 
                    formData : $('#loginForm').serialize() 
            },
            type: 'post',                  
            async: 'true',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
            contentType: "application/json",
            beforeSend: function() {
                // This callback function will trigger before data is sent
                $.mobile.loading("show"); // This will show ajax spinner
            },
            complete: function() {
                // This callback function will trigger on data sent/received complete
                 $.mobile.loading("hide"); // This will hide ajax spinner
            },
            success: function (result) {
                if(result.SUCCESS) {
                    $("#second").pagecontainer("change");           
                } else {
                    alert('Logon unsuccessful!');
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr,ajaxOptions,thrownError) {
                alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                alert(xhr.status);
                alert(thrownError);
            }
        });                  
    } else {
        alert('Please fill User ID and Password!');
    }  

    return false; // cancel original event to prevent form submitting

});   

});
```

I can go to "second.cfm" without any errors. It displays:

```
{"MSG":"User Logged in","SUCCESS":true}
```

I played around with the returning JSON but that didn't help either.

What do you think returns this SyntaxError? It is driving me nuts.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like an error in second.cfm when it receives the form data.  Try a REST client, like Postman, so you can mimic what your page is doing properly.